# Informing the user that a score was submitted to Game Center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod, game-center

Is there any method to tell the user that his score submitted successfully or just use an alert view.

I mean something like the Game Center welcome message: "Welcome Back, user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Game Center score submission implements a block callback which you can use to handle errors or successful submission. This is a function copied directly from the developer documentation:

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category{
  GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease];
  scoreReporter.value = score;

  [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil){
      //There was an error submitting the score.
    }else {
      //The score was successfully submitted.
    }
  }];
}
```

In terms of the user interface, like the sliding "welcome back" view, you'll have to make your own user interface for that. (I just use `UIAlertview`, but that's totally up to you.)

Answer (score 0):

> I mean something like the Game Center welcome message: "Welcome Back,
>   user"

You can use GKNotificationBanner on iOS 5.

[Have a look at the reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GameKit/Reference/GKNotificationBanner_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)